# Wubi + Multiple Windows Installations

Tags: wubi

I have a question about the Windows installer: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows If today I have two distinct Windows XP installations (one in English and one in Russian) and when I boot up, I can choose between the English and Russian installation, will I be able, after installing the Ubutnu Windows Installer, to select between English/Russian and Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Wubi uses the Windows boot manager (there is only one). And that's what you are using to boot into your different XP installs.